# Hide completed orders from sales/orders

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, filter, order-grid, status

In sales/orders is it possible to hide completed orders ? using something like filters.

or can I filter the status column with more than one status ?

Comment: which magento version?

Comment: Are u want to show order grid with out complete order?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: yes I want to show order grid with out complete order. but only when I want to not permanently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The observer way:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
        <observers>
            <vendor_module_salesgrid>
                <model>module/observer</model>
                <method>filterGrid</method>
            </vendor_module_salesgrid>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
</events>
```

Then in your `module/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer 
{
    public function filterGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq', 'complete'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento sales order grid collection generate from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`  at class `_prepareCollection` function.

**you need to modify the collection from here.**

***So you need to override that class***

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{ 
  protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
            // filter ty status 
        $collection ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq', 'complete'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `neq` instead of `nin` ?

Comment: you can also do it via an observer see my answer ;)

Comment: yup i know that....