# Hide completed order in magento 1.9 order panel

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order, order-grid

Please can anyone help me with step to step on how to create an observer on this page: 
[Hide completed orders from sales/orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112975/hide-completed-orders-form-sales-orders/188744#188744)
I have created **observer.xml** in `app/etc/modules/` with the code below:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
        <observers>
            <vendor_module_salesgrid>
                <model>module/observer</model>
                <method>filterGrid</method>
            </vendor_module_salesgrid>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
</events>
```

and also **observer.php** is created in `app/etc/modules/model` with the code below:

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer 
{
    public function filterGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq', 'complete'));
    }
}
```

but I couldn't get it to work
Thank you.

Update:

For some reason it did not work.
I did as you explained then created **hide_complete.xml** in the `app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Hide_Complete>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Hide_Complete>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Is there something that I am missing my folder path is: `app/code/local/Hide/Complete`
Thank you

Comment: I have added the issue that I have with it. Thank you

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?

Comment: Can you please addfull  pathes to your files? Here was somthing like observer.xml???

Comment: Those are actually the paths I used, I am not sure if I am correct. Your help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63642/discussion-between-adeola-adeoti-and-sv3n).

Answer (score 1):

Your files are just in the wrong directories ... just create an extension and

1. add your `Your_Module.xml` to `app/etc/modules/`
2. your code from `observer.xml` belongs to `app/code/POOL/Your/Module/etc/config.xml`
3. and `Òbserver.php` goes to `app/code/POOL/Your/Module/Model/`